# Erro ClassNotFoundException no RecyclerView$SavedState

Tags: java, android

Quando passo um tempo sem mexer na aplicação e volto para ela, dá esse erro:

```
E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$SavedState, e: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$SavedState
```

erro completo aqui:

```
 11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fabiano.ifprof/com.example.fabiano.ifprof.ShowFaltas}: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$SavedState
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$SavedState
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:1958)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1846)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2112)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:1568)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1903)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2083)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:208)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1167)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.onRestoreInstanceState(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:175)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(MenuBuilder.java:349)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.restorePresenterStates(MenuBuilder.java:361)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.onRestoreInstanceState(NavigationView.java:191)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:6278)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1211)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1215)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1215)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1215)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1215)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:6257)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1606)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:847)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:819)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1096)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1629)
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667) 
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935) 
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687) 
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625) 
    11-16 00:07:58.835 21709-21709/com.example.fabiano.ifprof E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```